# Code throws NetworkOnMainThread Exception despite being in another thread

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I have a problem with one thing in my app.
When I start the app in the debugger through, it throws me an error
NetworkOnMainThreadException.
More specifically when connecting to the web-server in thread(not main) throws an exception
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java).
So, the app tries to make a network call on the main thread, but the code is surrounded in another thread.

Problematic code is in a void called from onResume. Below I attach my code.

I've tried surrounding whole code in another thread, but still - NetworkOnMainThread

```java
final Runnable checker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(null);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL endpoint = new URL("###");
                    HttpsURLConnection conn =
                            (HttpsURLConnection) endpoint.openConnection(); //Here it throws mentioned Exception
                    if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        InputStream response = conn.getInputStream();
                        String results = iStreamToString(response);
                        if(UserIdResults.equals("0")){
                            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
                        }else {
                            //Do Something
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(checker, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is mostly likely caused by this line:

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
```

As written, `this` refers to the inner `Runnable` (the one you've expressed as a closure). That causes your network-executing `Runnable` to be run by the `Handler`, which is, of course, on the main thread.

You probably meant to run `checker`, in which case you should just use `checker` in place of `this`.